# Margin in question answers homework

Tags: formatting, margins

How can I remove the margin on the answers page (answers to proposed questions) so they all line up?

[image]

My code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{color}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\setlength{\columnsep}{1cm}

%%%%%%%


%%%%%

\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}

\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.5pt} %Separator ruler width
\def\columnseprulecolor{\color{black}} %Separator ruler colour
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[lmargin=1.7cm,tmargin=3cm,rmargin=1.5cm,bmargin=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{setspace}
\headheight=14pt
\lhead{\lfloor $25 \text{Questões}$ \rfloor  \text{ Aprofundando a Física}} 

\rhead{ Prof. Jean Pegoraro} 
 % <==================================================
\cfoot{} % <============================================== no pagenumber

\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace} 
\usepackage[brazil]{babel} 
\usepackage{enumerate} 
\newcommand{\quest}[1]{ \vspace{.6cm} \noindent\textbf{Questão #1. } }

\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{graphicx}

%\usepackage{blindtext} % <======================= to generate dummy text

\everymath{\displaystyle}


\begin{document} 
 % \Blindtext % <================================= create dummy text here %


\newcommand{\opt}[3]{\begin{enumerate}[a) ] 
\item #1
\item #2
\item #3
\end{enumerate}}
\newcommand{\otp}[2]{\begin{enumerate}[a) ] 
\item #1
\item #2
\end{enumerate}}




\rfoot{\textit{ \resizebox{!}{0.25cm}{Outubro de 2021}}}

\bigskip


\noindent\textbf{Questão 1.}    .....

 
\quest{2}....
\begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=6cm]{2.jpg}
\end{center}
 
\quest{3}....
.
.
.


 \newpage
 
\begin{center}
    \resizebox{!}{0.5cm}{Answers}
\end{center}


\textbf{1.} \noindent$ V = \sqrt{\frac{GM}{R_T}}$
\hfill$   \textbf{2. } a=\sqrt{R^2 + D^2}$
\hfill$ \textbf{3. } v_c = \frac{v_B}{2 \sin \alpha}; a_c = \frac{v^2_B}{2 l \sin^3 \alpha}$
\hfill$  \quest{4}\ (D)$
 \hfill$  \quest{5}\ (D)$
 \hfill$  \quest{6} \ (D)$
 \hfill$ \quest{7}\ (A) $ 
 \hfill$  \quest{9}\ (B)$
 \hfill$  \quest{10}\ (D)$ 
 \hfill$ \quest{12}\ (B)$
 \hfill$  \quest{15}\ (C)$
 \hfill$  \quest{16}\ (A)$
 \hfill$  \quest{17} \ (A)$
 \hfill$ \quest{18}\ (B) $ 
 \hfill$  \quest{21}\ (A)$
 \hfill$  \quest{23}\ (C)$ 
 \hfill$  \quest{24}\ (A)$
 \hfill$  \quest{25}\ (E)$ 
 
\end{document}
```

I would like a model like this: [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution you can better tailor to your needs:

\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lllll}
Domanda 1 (C) & Domanda 2 (A) & Domanda 3 (B) & Domanda 4 (A) & Domanda 5 (C) \
Domanda 6 (A) & Domanda 7 (D) & Domanda 8 (B) & Domanda 9 (A) & Domanda 10 (C) \
Domanda 11 (C) & Domanda 12 (C) & Domanda 13 (B) & Domanda 14 (D) & Domanda 15 (A) \
\end{tabular}
\begin{tabular}{llll}
P1 $\sin x$ & P2 $7 cm$ (A) & P3 $\frac{x+1}{2x-1}$  & P4 $\cos \frac{x}{2}$\
P5 $2\cos 3x$ & P6 $\tan 2x$ & P7 $x^2-3x$ & P8 $\frac{\sin x}{\cos x -\sin x}$\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}

The output is :

[image]